# PHP code correction requested while creating a dynamic unordered list

Tags: php

I am stuck in creating a dynamic unordered list using php.
Regarding Database, i have following tables:

1. Users - contains the user information (userid and username)
2. Groups - contains the groups information (groupid and group description)
3. SubGroups - contains the sub group information (subgroupid and subgroup description)
4. Groupitems - contains the combination of group with their subgourp item (groupid and subgroupid)
5. usergroups - contains the information that user have rights of the groups (userid and groupid)

Now using the above tables, i want to write the script in my php file to get an dynamic list which shows in Hierarchy like.

GroupID-1

```
 SubgroupID1

 SubgroupID2
```

GroupID-2

```
 SubgroupID1

 SubgroupID2
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php 
$qry_secs="SELECT DISTINCT groupid FROM usersgroup WHERE userid =0"; 
$result_secs = mysql_query($qry_secs);
while($row_secs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_secs)) { 
echo '<ul>'.$row_secs['groupid']; 
$newqry = "SELECT distinct subgroupid FROM groupitems WHERE groupid ".$row_secs['groupid'];
 $result = mysql_query($newqry);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
  echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row['subgroupid'] . '</a></li>';  
  } 
  echo '</ul>';
 } ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you should post a bit of sourcecode you have at this point. This just sounds like 'please do my homework'. ;)

Comment: Show what you did write (in the question... :-)

Comment: @user3354952 Please note that you can always edit your question to add more details, so do not mention them in the comments they might be missed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `</a>` in the while loop to close your anchor.
so:

```
echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row['subgroupid'] . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Thanks mark for the answer. but adding </a> is not affecting the output.

Answer (score 0):

**you should use the`</a>` in another echo tag.**

```
echo '<li><a href="#">' . $row['subgroupid'] . '</li>'; 
echo '</a>'; 

       or

   echo '<li>'.<a href="#">.. $row['subgroupid'] . '</a>'.'</li>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but "</a>" closing anchor tag by both ways have not effect on the output. Besides, i have also added the </a> tag in the PHP code of my request to help in understanding the question better.